# Is it possible to have a form that always stays on top and passes clicks through it?

Tags: winforms, topmost, click-through

I'm trying to create a form that always stays on top to show information but doesn't prevent the user from clicking on something in the window behind that form. I want the form to be semi-transparent so that you can see and access what's behind it without moving or closing the window. I'm using Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019.

This question has been asked before - 6 years ago but there is not a satisfying answer so I thought I'd bring it up again.

Original post:
[Click through-able form that stays always on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662983/click-through-able-form-that-stays-always-on-top)

Comment: Have you seen this: [Transparent window layer that is click-through and always stays on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077236/transparent-window-layer-that-is-click-through-and-always-stays-on-top) ?

Comment: You need a DirectX Overlay for something like this. A layered transparent Form (created adding `WS_EX_LAYERED` and `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` to `CreateParams.ExStyle`) set to TopMost will only stay on top if no other Window is also set as TopMost. You could use a Timer to fight that, but the other app may do the same, so... not good for the User Experience (glitches, flickering, bad mojo overall).